# Quick Wolfram Question

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries

This is my code so far:

```
For[i=2, i<10, i++, Solve[x^i == x+1 && x >0]]
```

I would like to sum up all the x values that it outputs. How can I do so?

Comment: `Total@Table[x /. First@NSolve[x^i == x + 1 && x > 0], {i, 2, 9}]`

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951)

Answer (score 5):

Quick answer

```
Total@Table[ x /. Solve[x^i == x + 1 && x > 0][[1]] , {i, 2, 9}]//N
(*9.76035*)
```

Comment: I ran the program by the way. It computes all the numbers positive numbers x s.t. x^n = x+1. Numbers like 1.618, 1.3247, 1.2207, etc. Its a sequence approaching 1 in the limit. Then I added all the decimal parts: .618 + .3247 + .2207 etc and found that it was divergent. Then I took the first 1000 sums and compared it to the first 10000 sums and I found a constant ratio of 1.596. Is there a concept for this?  The ratio of divergent sums computed at logarithmic intervals.

Comment: +1, also: `Sum[x /. Solve[x^i == x + 1 && x > 0][[1]], {i, 2, 9}] // N`